# Order by equal name and 6 digit to 7 digit value then from lowest to highest

Tags: sql

This code attempts to sort my values by number of digits, from 6 to 7, then from lowest to highest numerically and equal Name.

```
SELECT * FROM score ORDER BY ID DESC ,Name DESC
```

I have sets of data in my table and I always get:

```
ID            Name
992425        a
992444        b
992199        b
1001111       a
```

I expect result

```
ID            Name
992425        a
1001111       a
992199        b
992444        b
```

How to sort by number of digits, from 6 to 7, then ID from lowest to highest numerically and equal name?

The Name is an NVARCHAR column.
The ID is int column.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sort you want, use:

```
order by name, id asc
```

But if `id` is really a string -- as your initial results suggest -- then the sort will not be what you expect.  One simple method is to convert the id to a number:

```
order by name, cast(id as int) asc
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to reverse the columns in order by clause as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM score ORDER by Name, id
```